# Ruby on Rails: Complex Form Generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, form-for

So I'm fairly new with Rails and I'm trying to figure out the best way of generation a complex form. The basic idea is that a user places an `order`, each `order` is made up of one or more `pizza_order`, each `pizza_order` consists of either a `special` pizza or just a `pizza`. The main issue I'm having right now is how do I generate a dynamic form where the user can consistently generate an arbitrary amount of new `pizza_order` models?

My thought was to have a button that they would press, and each time the button is pressed to render a partial view that consists of the fields necessary for a new `pizza_order`. When the user presses submit the `order` is generated, along with an array of new `pizza_order` models that are associated with that `order`. These are what my models look like so far.

**Order**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :pizza_orders
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pizza_orders
end
```

**Pizza Order**

```
class PizzaOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizza, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :order
end
```

**Pizza**

```
class Pizza < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :toppings
  has_many :pizza_orders, as: :pizza
  belongs_to :crust
  validates :crust, presence: true
end
```

**Special**

```
class Special < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizza
  validates :pizza, :presence => true
  validates :cost, :presence => true
end
```

I'm fairly lost on what the controller and view will look like, so far this is the general layout for my view, I'll worry about filling in the attributes later, I'm more concerned with getting the proper rails fields set up.

```
<%= form_for @order do |t| %>
  <%= t.fields_for t.pizza_orders do |po| %>
  <% end%>

  <!--Insert new pizza_orders after marker -->
  <span id="marker"></span>
  <%= button_tag "New Order", :type => 'button', :id => 'test' %>
  <%= t.submit "Place Order" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your plight correctly, this is a job for Cocoon!  Cocoon allows you to generate dynamic nested fields (as many as you want).

**So what I'd do is:**

[install the cocoon gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/cocoon)

Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhdzE1yNs-0) You can fast forward to where he's showing how to dynamically add ingredients to recipes but really this entire tutorial is a FANTASTIC reference that will save you lots of googling.

Then in your pizza order view, render a partial (just as you said) only do it with cocoon.

```
<%= simple_form_for @order do |t| %>
  <%= t.simple_fields_for :pizza_orders do |po| %>
        <%= render 'order_fields', p: po %>
  <% end%>
    <div class="add-field"><%= link_to_add_association 'Add Pizza Order', t, :pizza_orders %></div>

  <!--Insert new pizza_orders after marker -->
  <span id="marker"></span>
  <%= button_tag "New Order", :type => 'button', :id => 'test' %>
  <%= t.submit "Place Order" %>
<% end %>
```

Then create the partial `_order_fields.html.erb` and put whatever fields you need as follows:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= p.input :order_field1 %>
  <%= p.input :order_field2 %>
  <%= p.input :order_field3 %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "Delete", p %>
</div>
```

Remember to do your strong params just like any other nesting and you should be all set!  Also make sure the parent model `accepts_nested_attributes_for` the child and is allowed to destroy it.

**Now, regarding the rest of your code:**
I think you might be making your models overly complicated.  While I don't know the fields you're dealing with my intuition is that your use of polymorphic associations is unnecessary.
At a glance I would set it up like this
**Two, maybe three models:**

1. Order
2. Pizza
3. Toppings? (another use for cocoon)

`Order` would `has_many :pizzas`

Data about crust type, price of the pizza would be saved within each pizza's model.  Like so: `rails g model Pizza price:decimal crust:string type:string`.  If it's a special, let the type be "special."

Extra model associations muddies your code, hinders you from using available tools and may lead to increased blood pressure.  Pizza is one of life's simple pleasures and should be left unburdened by polymorphic associations; for the sake of yourself, don't over-complicate it. :-D

## Edit

You will need the [Simple Forms gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/simple_form) to copy what I have above directly.  (I highly recommend it.)  Please note that you will need to change `form_for` to `simple_form_for` and `fields_for` to `simple_fields_for`.

Comment: This is a great start! I've been fiddling around with it for a while but haven't been able to get it to render my partial view for some reason, but I'll keep looking at it

Comment: No it just wasn't rendering, but I figured it out now. I didn't realize the partial naming convention was very important, as well as including the class `nested-fields`, and finally the `add_association_link` needed to be after the field for the `fields_for` section.

Comment: Well now I am getting an error. I get `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)` when my partial is simply
`<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= t.input :quantity %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "delete", p %>
</div>`

It says the error is line `t.input :quantity`

Comment: Am I totally off? I don't think you can use `f.input` with straight Rails. That's Simple Form syntax, right?

Comment: I think that may be the case. I've changed it to `<%=link_to_add_association 'add pizza_order', order_form, :pizza_orders%>` and the new problem that arises is `undefined local variable or method order_form` when the partial is trying to use  `<%= order_form.label :quantity %>`

Comment: @DillonDrobena Lanny is right, I forgot what using just the basic rails form requires. If I were you, I'd add the simple form gem so that you don't have to screw around with specifying your data types. Simple_form looks at your database to automatically set the datatype in your form. If you prefer to do it without the extra gem, just change .input in your fields accordingly. I'll add the link at the top.

Comment: I'll try the simple_form gem. I tried just using the straightforward `label` `text_field` but the issue was the actual variable I was trying to pass between partials. In this case its the `order_form` variable

Comment: @DillonDrobena I'm not sure what might be wrong as I don't see your code. If you want, feel free to post your code in a gist (https://gist.github.com/) or pastie (http://pastie.org/) or something and send me a link.  I'll take a look.

Comment: Well I fixed it...this gem has been a bit frustrating. Apparently its important to keep your formbuilder named `f` as shown in the github examples. Once I changed my variable name to `f` it started working again. This gem feels a bit restrictive

Comment: @DillonDrobena glad to hear it's working!  Cocoon can be a bit restrictive; it also doesn't play ball with asynchronicity.... BUT it's better than writing it from scratch as far as I'm concerned.  Take care!